# Pinescript for structural pivots

Tags: debugging, logic, pine-script, specifications, trading

I amd trying to mark a bar a structural pivot high (SPH) or structural pivot low (SPL) as per the conditions below:
A bar is marked as an SPL  by finding a combination of 3 bars, an Anchor Bar, Bar 1 and Bar 2.Bar 1 and Bar 2 should have a higher high and a higher close relative to the Anchor Bar in order to qualify as a legitimate SPL. The complication happens for the fact that Anchor Bar, Bar 1 and Bar 2 need not be consecutive.They can be far apart from themselves.To solve this problem, the script generates 3-bar Combinations of all the bars from the last pivot to the current bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Structural Pivots", overlay=true)

// Function to check if a point is a Structural Pivot Low (SPL)
isSPL(anchorHigh, anchorClose, bar1High, bar1Close, bar2High, bar2Close) =>
    bar1High > anchorHigh and bar1Close > anchorClose and bar2High > bar1High and bar2Close > bar1Close

// Declare lastPivotIndex as an integer
var int lastPivotIndex = na
lastPivotIndex := bar_index - ta.barssince(high[1] > high and high[1] > high[2])

// Array to store SPL bars
var int[] splBarIndexes = array.new_int(0)

// Iterate through bars from the last pivot to the current bar
for i = lastPivotIndex to bar_index
    // Iterate through previous bars for Anchor Bar
    for j = lastPivotIndex to i - 2
        var anchorHigh = high[j]
        var anchorClose = close[j]
        
        // Iterate through bars between Anchor Bar and the current bar for Bar 1
        for k = j + 1 to i - 1
            var bar1High = high[k]
            var bar1Close = close[k]
            
            var bar2High = high[i]
            var bar2Close = close[i]
            
            // Check for SPL
            if (isSPL(anchorHigh, anchorClose, bar1High, bar1Close, bar2High, bar2Close))
                array.push(splBarIndexes, i)

// Plot SPL with blue triangles below the bars
plotshape(series=array.includes(splBarIndexes, bar_index - lastPivotIndex) ? 1 : na, title="SPL", color=color.blue, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
```

I seem to be lost here. Also dont know how to debug this as pinescript doesnt have print facility

Comment: "Also dont know how to debug this as pinescript doesnt have print facility". Oh, it does, alright! See the new [log.info()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_log.info) and also [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#debugging) debugging techniques.